# YII2 Insert something in array made by arrayhelper::map()

Tags: arrays, yii2-advanced-app

How to insert or push something to an existing array?

I have this code...

```
$brgys=ArrayHelper::map(LibBrgy::find()
->where(['city_code'=>$model->city_code])
->all(),'brgy_code','brgy_name');
```

the result is..

```
array(4) {
[166816001]=> string(7) "BAGYANG" 
[166816002]=> string(5) "BARAS" 
[166816003]=> string(8) "BITAUGAN" 
[166816004]=> string(7) "BOLHOON" 
}
```

How do I add an empty value to make it like the following...

```
array(4) {
[166816001]=> string(7) "BAGYANG" 
[166816002]=> string(5) "BARAS" 
[166816003]=> string(8) "BITAUGAN" 
[166816004]=> string(7) "BOLHOON"
['']=>""
}
```

so that in the html form I would have this..

```
<select id="tblspbub-brgy_code" class="form-control" name="TblSpBub[brgy_code]">
<option value="166816001">BAGYANG</option>
<option value="166816002">BARAS</option>
<option value="166816003">BITAUGAN</option>
<option value="166816004">BOLHOON</option>
<option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to modify array to achieve this.

Drop-down list has special option for this called `prompt`.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'code')->dropDownList($items, ['prompt' => '']) ?>
```

It will render additional `option` with empty `value` in `select` with given `name`.

You can read more about [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeDropDownList%28%29-detail).